# Android default notification margin

Tags: android, notifications, android-screen-support

Good day. 
I created fully custom view for notification. But on different devices left (start) margin different.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/notificationContentInsert"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/notificationContentInsert"
    >
```

where notificationContentInsert is 16dp in values/dimens.xml

F.e.

- On my OnePlus 6 (1080 x 2280) with 16dp marginStart all notifications
  (include system notifications and others like gmail) has same start
  margin and looks fine.
- But on Samsung Tab A (9.7", 1024x768) 16dp looks smaller than another
  notifications.

Also i tried to use sdk attribute *android:dimen/notification_content_margin_start*
but this attribute is private and i obtain compile exception
**AAPT: error: resource android:dimen/notification_content_margin_start is private.**

Is there way to get device specified notification content padding? Thanks

Comment: Did you come up with a solution for this issue? I need to do the same thing as well.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul unfortunately no

Answer (score 4):

Adding static margins or paddings can bring up issues when your app is running in Android 12.

If the `targetSdkVersion` is less than 31, you will still get to use the full notification area for your customizable notifications.

If you add padding in the layout file and you change the targetSdkVersion to 31, the notification will look weird in Android 12 devices. This becomes a pain if you are building an sdk that has notification capabilities in it. I had a similar situation and decided to add padding after checking the `targetSdkVersion` programmatically.

```java
ApplicationInfo info = context.getApplicationInfo();
if (info.targetSdkVersion < Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
    int dp16 = Utils.dpToPx(16, context);
    remoteViews.setViewPadding(R.id.notification_container, dp16, dp16, dp16, dp16);
}
```

Where `R.id.notification_container` is the root view of my custom notification's layout.

The value 16 looks good to me. But, please let me know if there are better ways to obtain the value from the OS without having to call `Resource.getIdentifier()` method.

Comment: Resource.getIdentifier() and remoteViews.setViewPadding() works well on devices except Xiaomi. I dont understand why???

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but the solution is simple. Instead of using margins, we will use padding in the parent view, and then we will get the amount and set the padding in code. We will start with a default value, in case the code fails.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/notify_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
```

Then in code we will use `Resources.getIdentifier()` to get the value. We soround it with try/catch, so in worst case, it uses the default. Here is the code:

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_notification_content_layout);
try {
    // We are assuming start and end are same. If we want to be nitty, we will get them separately, and then check which to use for left and which for righht.
    int identifier = context.getResources().getIdentifier("notification_content_margin_start", "dimen", "android");
    if (identifier != 0) {
        int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(identifier);
        contentView.setViewPadding(R.id.notify_layout, padding, 0, padding, 0);
        Log.d("setViewPadding", "Setting padding to: " + padding);
    } else {
        Log.d("setViewPadding", "Failed to find padding");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("setViewPadding", "Failed to set padding");
}
```

This code was tested, and seems to work well. We have to use padding, as there is no setMargins function for RemoteViews.

Enjoy, Lionscribe

Comment: Seem to work on Virtual Devices but on the real Xiaomi Phone, the margin is too big

Answer (score 1):

No need to set any margin and padding to the layout. Apply NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle to your notification with setStyle method as below. This API allows you to provide a custom layout for the content area normally occupied by the title and text content, while still using system decorations for the notification icon, timestamp, sub-text, and action buttons.

```
android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new 
android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(parent);
nBuilder.setContentTitle("Your title")
   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
   . // add your other settings
   .
   .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle()); //this makes your notification similar to other system notifications
```

Comment: This kind of takes away the luxury of using the full space for expanded notifications in older devices. But for recent android versions this seems like a good option.